# Cumulative data indexing in elastic search using river for Oracle

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch

I'm using Oracle Database and I'm implementing search using elastic search.
We are using river and execute every 5 mins to pull the data which is updated after latest execution.

If river always work fine, then there is no issue.
In some case, Oracle have to be run for dedicated service, then pull the data which is updated between 5 mins isn't work properly.

So I think we have to pull the data from last executed time and how could I do it ? 
Is it possible to keep the last success execution time in DB or Elastic Search ?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods come to mind. One is to add a column to your data table(s) to indicate if the data has been extracted. This requires you to update each row as it's extracted, which may seem onerous, but it gives you a very clear picture of what has been extracted and eliminates the need to do date/time comparisons which I have found can be relatively time consuming. I prefer this solution as I've found it to be pretty fool-proof in the past.

The second method is to have a "settings" table, and to record the time-of-last-successful-extract in the settings table. In my opinion this is the less desirable of the alternatives as it doesn't explicitly indicate which rows have been extracted.

YMMV.

Share and enjoy.